# Asking for ideas to plot large variables against their R squared values (drawn from linear regression models) in R (preferably using GGPLOT2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, lattice

I had to build 231 linear regression models for my project. After running 231 models, I am left with 231 R squared values that I have to present in a plot against the variable names. Since 231 R squared values are too many for a table, I am looking for a plotting ideas so I can show R squared values as y-axis and variable names as x-axis. When I run dput(head(df, 5)) I get this (which may give you an idea of my data):

```
structure(list(Band = c(402, 411, 419, 427, 434), R.squared = c(0.044655015122032, 
0.852028718800355, 0.818617476505653, 0.825782272278991, 0.860844967662728
), Adj.Rsquared = c(-0.0614944276421867, 0.835587465333728, 0.798463862784058, 
0.806424746976656, 0.845383297403031), Intercept = c(0.000142126282140086, 
-0.00373545760470339, -0.00258909036368109, 0.000626075834918527, 
-3.3448513588372e-05), Slope = c(-0.00108714482110104, 0.393380133190131, 
0.443463459485279, 0.503881831479685, 0.480162723468755)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Please note that my full data have 231 observations and I want to plot the variable band (as a factor) as an x-axis and R squared as a y-axis. I already tried geom_point() in ggplot2 but it looks very messy and complicated to understand. Any ideas?

Update: when I use the suggested code by @Duck I get this plot which is a little messy to use for a scientific presentation.[image: plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a large number of values you can dodge the labels in axis, here an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(mdf,aes(x=factor(Band),y=R.squared))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge=2))+
  coord_flip()
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
mdf <- structure(list(Band = c(402, 411, 419, 427, 434, 412, 421, 429, 
437, 444, 422, 431, 439, 447, 454, 432, 441, 449, 457, 464), 
    R.squared = c(0.044655015122032, 0.852028718800355, 0.818617476505653, 
    0.825782272278991, 0.860844967662728, 0.044655015122032, 
    0.852028718800355, 0.818617476505653, 0.825782272278991, 
    0.860844967662728, 0.044655015122032, 0.852028718800355, 
    0.818617476505653, 0.825782272278991, 0.860844967662728, 
    0.044655015122032, 0.852028718800355, 0.818617476505653, 
    0.825782272278991, 0.860844967662728), Adj.Rsquared = c(-0.0614944276421867, 
    0.835587465333728, 0.798463862784058, 0.806424746976656, 
    0.845383297403031, -0.0614944276421867, 0.835587465333728, 
    0.798463862784058, 0.806424746976656, 0.845383297403031, 
    -0.0614944276421867, 0.835587465333728, 0.798463862784058, 
    0.806424746976656, 0.845383297403031, -0.0614944276421867, 
    0.835587465333728, 0.798463862784058, 0.806424746976656, 
    0.845383297403031), Intercept = c(0.000142126282140086, -0.00373545760470339, 
    -0.00258909036368109, 0.000626075834918527, -3.3448513588372e-05, 
    0.000142126282140086, -0.00373545760470339, -0.00258909036368109, 
    0.000626075834918527, -3.3448513588372e-05, 0.000142126282140086, 
    -0.00373545760470339, -0.00258909036368109, 0.000626075834918527, 
    -3.3448513588372e-05, 0.000142126282140086, -0.00373545760470339, 
    -0.00258909036368109, 0.000626075834918527, -3.3448513588372e-05
    ), Slope = c(-0.00108714482110104, 0.393380133190131, 0.443463459485279, 
    0.503881831479685, 0.480162723468755, -0.00108714482110104, 
    0.393380133190131, 0.443463459485279, 0.503881831479685, 
    0.480162723468755, -0.00108714482110104, 0.393380133190131, 
    0.443463459485279, 0.503881831479685, 0.480162723468755, 
    -0.00108714482110104, 0.393380133190131, 0.443463459485279, 
    0.503881831479685, 0.480162723468755)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

The suggestion from **@DaveArmstrong** is very helpful too (Many thanks and credits to him):

```
#Code 2
ggplot(mdf,aes(x=reorder(factor(Band), R.squared, mean),y=R.squared))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge=2))+
  coord_flip()
```

Output:

[image]

Another option:

```
#Code 3
ggplot(mdf,aes(x=reorder(factor(Band), R.squared, mean),y=R.squared))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_segment( aes(x=reorder(factor(Band), R.squared, mean),
                    xend=reorder(factor(Band), R.squared, mean),
                    y=0,
                    yend=R.squared))+
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge=2))+
  coord_flip()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I think @Duck's answer is a good one, but you might get more mileage by ordering the `Band` factor by `R.squared`, so instead of `factor(Band)`, you could use `reorder(factor(Band), R.squared, mean)`.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong It is a great suggestion, let me include that with credit to you!

Comment: Thanks @Duck and DaveArmstrong for the suggestions! I tried the suggested code. It only looks fine if you have small amounts of band names, but in my case, I have 231 band names and when I produced the plot it looked really messy. I would like to show you the plot I get with the code you provided, but I am not sure how to add it to the comment section here (I am a new user of stackoverflow).

Comment: @Zav Edit your question, and add the screenshot on it so that we can see it.

Comment: @Duck I did edit and add the screenshot on the post. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Zav Add more dodge like `guide_axis(n.dodge=3)` and `theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=5))` let me know how that goes!

Comment: @Duck it only made things slightly better than the previous one, but the plot is still too far from being OK to be shared on a presentation.

Answer (score 2):

What about a heatmap.

```
dat <- tibble(
  Band = 100:330, 
  R.squared = runif(231, 0, 1), 
  Adj.Rsquared = R.squared - runif(231, 0, .1)
) %>% 
  mutate(Band = reorder(factor(Band), R.squared, mean)) 

q <- c(0, quantile(dat$R.squared, c(.2,.4, .6, .8)), 1)
dat <- dat %>% mutate(group=cut(R.squared, breaks=q))
levels(dat$group) <- c("Quntile 1", "Quintile 2", "Quintile 3", "Quintile 4", "Quintile 5")

ggplot(dat, aes(x=1, y = Band, fill=R.squared)) + 
  geom_tile(col="white") + 
  facet_wrap(~group, scales="free_y", nrow=1) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=NULL) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c() + 
  labs(x = "", y="", fill=expression(R^2)) + 
  theme(legend.position="top", 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=10))
```

[image]

This would be another option, where the label is inside the cell:

```
R2 <- matrix(dat$R.squared, ncol=21, nrow=11)
txt <- matrix(as.character(dat$Band), ncol=21, nrow=11)

dat2 <- tibble(
  R.squared = c(R2), 
  Band = c(txt), 
  row = rep(1:11, 21), 
  col = rep(21:1, each=11)
)

ggplot(dat2, aes(x=row, y=col, fill=R.squared)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Band), color="white") + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option="B") + 
  theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
  labs(x = "", y="", fill=expression(R^2))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the plot ideas! Although these heatmaps look very good, they are not helping me with how much detailed information I want to show. I guess I will have to go with a plot where I plot the bands as an integer or something like that.

Comment: @Zav other alternatives are possible, too - you could imagine a histogram where the bars are built by the names of the bands or, depending on how you make your presentations, including an interactive plot where the tooltip hover includes the band name, the R-squared and the adjusted R-squared using `ggplot()` and `ggplotly()` would also be a possibility.  However, if the main goal is to have people in a presentation be able to clearly read 230 numbers and their respective labels from a slide I am not sure there is a display out there that fits the bill.